# Why is regex working only if function scoped variable is declared before the local doCount function

Tags: javascript, function, scope, var

I have some sample code at the following link: [working sample](https://js.do/sun21170/regex-issue-with-local-scoped-variable-and-function).

```js
var a = "sd 1234 abc \n";

function removeNewLineCharacter1() {
  doCount(a);

  var _trimNewLineCharsRegExp = /(^[\n\r]+)|([\n\r]+$)/g;

  function doCount(g) {
    var originalLength = g.length;
    g = g.replace(_trimNewLineCharsRegExp, "");
    console.log("original length :" + originalLength + " and final length : " + g.length);
  }
}

function removeNewLineCharacter2() {
  var _trimNewLineCharsRegExp = /(^[\n\r]+)|([\n\r]+$)/g;

  doCount(a);

  function doCount(g) {
    var originalLength = g.length;
    g = g.replace(_trimNewLineCharsRegExp, "");
    console.log("original length :" + originalLength + " and final length : " + g.length);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="removeNewLineCharacter1(); return false;">Remove new line character(s) 1</button>
<button id="btn1" onclick="removeNewLineCharacter2(); return false;">Remove new line character(s) 2</button>
```

When I click on the the button that says `Remove new line character(s) 1` the new line character is not trimmed from the string `a`. However, when I click on the button that says `Remove new line character(s) 2` then the new line character gets removed. Both these buttons are calling different functions when they are clicked, but the difference between these called functions is simply that the regex expression variable `_trimNewLineCharsRegExp` is declared before `doCount` local scoped function in the called function that works.

**Question**

Why is the new line character not being removed by the first button onclick function?

Comment: Sounds like a [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) issue: *"However JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations! This means that initialization doesn't happen until the associated line of code is executed, even if the variable was originally initialized then declared, or declared and initialized in the same line."*

Comment: So, maybe the variable `_trimNewLineCharsRegExp` is undefined in the first button click function and therefore, no trimming occurs. Does that sound correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables declared with `var` are hoisted, so it doesn't matter when it is *declared*.

The key here is when it is *assigned a value*.

In the first example, it is `undefined`, then you call the function (passing `undefined` to `g.replace`), then you give it a value.

In the second example, you give it a value before calling the function (so you pass `/(^[\n\r]+)|([\n\r]+$)/g` to `g.replace`).

Comment: So, a `var` with an assigment doesn't get hoisted?

Comment: @Sunil — The declaration of the variable is hoisted. The assignment isn't.

Comment: It gets hoisted, but hoisting affects only declaration and not initialization. If you have `console.log(x); var x = 3;` it will be like `var x; console.log(x); x = 3;`.

Comment: @CherryDT, yes I get it. So, the declaration part from the statement `var _trimNewLineCharsRegExp = /(^[\n\r]+)|([\n\r]+$)/g;` is getting hoisted, but the assigment part is not. Therefore, the value of the variable is undefined in first button click function.

Answer (score 2):

Variables defined with `var` get hoisted. This means that the declaration is moved a the top of the function. But they get `initialized` where you assign them a value.

In your case, in one instance you are initializing the variable before calling `doCount` and in another after.

This means that inside `removeNewLineCharacter1` `doCount` gets executed with a value of undefined for `_trimNewLineCharsRegExp`. This is where the difference comes from.